# OpenCV 3.0 из исходников и pkg-config в Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, qtcreator, opencv

Был когда-то собран OpenCV 3.0 beta из исходников. Подключал его в QtCreator 3.4.0 (Qt5.4.1) через pkg-config в Ubuntu 14.10:

```
unix {
   CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
   PKGCONFIG += opencv
}
```

Проекты нормально собирались, запускались и работали.

Вышли новая Ubuntu 15.04 и OpenCV 3.0 rc1. Обновил первое и пересобрал заново второе.

Сборка собственных проектов проходит на ура, все внешние зависимости подключаются, однако теперь при запуске программы из QtCreator или просто из терминала выдаёт, что не может найти подключаемые библиотеки OpenCV. Я понимаю, что можно просто указать переменную среды окружения LD_LIBRARY_PATH, но хотелось бы в общих чертах понять, а что собственно изменилось и как сделать так, чтобы было как раньше.

**Update:**
Команда ldd на проект выдаёт следующее:

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77cc000)
libopencv_core.so.3.0 => not found
libopencv_features2d.so.3.0 => not found
libopencv_highgui.so.3.0 => not found
libopencv_imgcodecs.so.3.0 => not found
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb76ae000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7661000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7644000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7488000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77cd000)
```

OpenCV установлен в "/usr/local/lib". Складывается ощущение, что "/usr/local" перестала видеться как место хранения библиотек. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: А сами библиотеки (libcv.so и другие) где лежат после сборки? Проверьте исполняемый файл вашего проекта с помощью `ldd` или `readelf`, с какими именно библиотеками он связан.

Comment: @velikodniy Обновил вопрос с выводом от ldd. Нужные файлы лежат в "/usr/local/lib".

Comment: Да, скорее всего не находит библиотеки. Можно попробовать запустить проект с `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="путь к библиотекам"` или использовать параметр `-rpath` у `gcc` при сборке. Если заработает, значит просто библиотеки не видит и надо в настройках системы покопаться. Других причин я и не вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего система не может найти библиотеки. Есть несколько способов решения этой проблемы.

Первый заключается в добавлении пути в переменную `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (список путей, по которым система ищет библиотеки). Для этого небходимо перед запуском программы выполнить команду:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib"
```

Она добавляет путь `/usr/local/lib` в конец переменной.

Второй способ заключается в изменении системных настроек. Для этого в директории `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/` создайте файл с именем, например, `99local.conf`, содержащий путь к библиотекам. (В вашем случае `/usr/local/lib`.)

Для того, чтобы изменения вступили в силу выполните от имени `root` команду `ldconfig`.

Третий способ — использование параметра `-rpath` компилятора `gcc`, который позволяет явно указать путь к библиотеке.

Comment: Благодарю, исчерпывающе. Решил воспользоваться вторым способом, полез в "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/" и обнаружил несколько разных файлов. В одном из них (libc.conf) нашёл уже имеющуюся строку с "/usr/local/lib", поэтому новый добавлять не стал, а просто из-под рута выполнил ldconfig. Теперь всё работает как раньше. Спасибо.